# What dress is expected at a post-service event in a synagogue?

Tags: minhag, gentiles, clothing

A non-Jew is invited to a birthday party to be held in the synagogue after services.  What level of dress is expected?  Would one be expected to dress as for Shabbat services, or would a more casual (but still nice) level of dress be acceptable because it's a party and not a service?  Does being a non-Jew make a difference?

Comment: Why can't you ask your friend?

Comment: http://www.jewfaq.org/shul.htm

Comment: Can this be edited to ask what is appropriate to wear to a shul.

Comment: Shirley, welcome to Mi Yodeya and I hope you enjoyed the party.  I've edited your question to make it more general; we avoid questions that seem to ask for individual rulings (which we aren't equipped to provide) in favor of ones that ask about the situation more generally.  Please feel free to [edit] further if I've accidentally changed too much.  Thanks for understanding, and I hope you enjoy the site -- perhaps our other 480 questions about [tag:gentiles] will interest you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not eligible for comments but I would like more proof that tsnius applies to non Jews. 
The gemoro in b'rochos doesnt seem to agree. A woman was wearing red clothing which is against tsnius and a rov tore it off her. Afterwards he found out she wasnt Jewish and paid her. 
It sounds from the gemoro that he had done wrong to tear her clothing. If as you say tsnius applies to goyim then what wrong did he do.

Comment: Didn't know. I thought it was obviuosly so. guess I might be wrong, though I can think of several explanations for that gemra even if tsnius applies goyim

Comment: What does this have to do with erva or makom michusa?  What does this have to do with etiquette or expectations of one people from another? How does this address the specific concerns as stated?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the bottom line is to make sure it doesn't reveal too much (which leades to...). Of course this definition has quite a lot of room for discussion but I believe the majority is [female assumed] :

- Skirt/dress below ankles.
- Sleeves past the elbows.
- Neck hole should cover the collar bone (base shirt..).

This was written from a male prespective, would be WISER to ask a female regarding the finer details ( more precisely the true ones )

(Noticed it is probably too late, but always worth finding out anyway, enjoy)

Can't understand if you meant you are jewish or not, but I'll just mention that Tzeni'ut is 'Avizeraihu' of Gilui arayot, that means 'tis a part of the commandment concerning sexual immorality [ one of The Seven Laws of Noah]. By jewish faith, as long as you are a descendant of Noah, and I'm pretty sure you are, ( well, Adam as well but we do not know of anyone else) it holds as much as obligation to you as well.

Answer (score 0):

The term "casual" has numerous meanings to various people these days. I agree with the comment above. I think that your friend who attends the synagogue can give you better guidance.

If not, assume that you should dress as if you are attending a nice affair but wear long sleeves and something with a high neckline. This is not a question regarding whether the rules of "modesty" apply the same way to Gentiles as they do to Jews. It is a question of respect and reverence for the synagogue and proper behavior.

I wouldn't consider entering a Christian service (assuming opinions allowing entry into a Church or service in a non Church) wearing a T shirt and crocks or going to a Gentile friend's birthday party held in a public place such as a nice restaurant dressed like that. And, if I were unsure, I would just ask the host what attire is appropriate.

Comment: Wouldn't "respect and reverence for the synagogue and proper behavior" mean dressing modestly even if doesn't aplly to you?

Comment: @Zeev Yes. That's my point. When going to a public affair, you wear what is respectful to both the host and the place you are going. Years ago, people wore tuxes when going to the theater, out of respect for the actors and the nature of the theater. Now, people wear torn jeans and sneaks. It doesn't belong there.